# "Cell populations" or "cells populations"?

Tags: grammaticality

A simple question, but I did the answer while googling.
I would like to say "The proposed method aims at delineating cells populations".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be singular in this case, as in **cell populations**. As a native speaker, I'd avoid an "s" here unless it was possessive (and therefore also had an associated apostrophe). I don't think your usage is possessive.

For proof, see this [ngrams graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cell+populations%2C+cells+populations&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccell%20populations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccells%20populations%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccell%20populations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccells%20populations%3B%2Cc0) showing that "cell populations" is much more common than "cell populations".

For explanation, it's a [noun modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), and these are apparently traditionally singular (although there is some change recently and they can be plural, sometimes).

Comment: I would put it more strongly: "cells populations" is a clear error (as indeed are "cell's populations" or "cells' populations"). The only option here is "cell populations".

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the answer! It's easier to remember with that rule. Sorry, I can't vote yet.